# "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.internal.IConfiguration.getConfigurationListeners()Ljava/util/List" while running TestNG framework

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am getting below error message while running TestNG framework on Eclipse (Oxygen version).

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.testng.internal.IConfiguration.getConfigurationListeners()Ljava/util/List
```

I am getting this error everytime when I execute testng.xml file. Can anyone please help me for this?

Comment: update the testng version greater than 6.8. it may resolve your problem

Comment: I am using updated testng version. Please suggest alternate solution.